# Use pre-installed Terraform plugins instead of downloading them with terraform init

Tags: terraform

While running `terraform init` when using Terraform `0.11.3` we are getting the following error:

> Initializing provider plugins...
>   - Checking for available provider plugins on https://releases.hashicorp.com...
>
> Error installing provider "template": Get
>   https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform-provider-template/: read tcp
>   172.25.77.25:53742->151.101.13.183:443: read: connection reset by peer.
>
> Terraform analyses the configuration and state and automatically
>   downloads plugins for the providers used. However, when attempting to
>   download this plugin an unexpected error occured.
>
> This may be caused if for some reason Terraform is unable to reach the
>   plugin repository. The repository may be unreachable if access is
>   blocked by a firewall.
>
> If automatic installation is not possible or desirable in your
>   environment, you may alternatively manually install plugins by
>   downloading a suitable distribution package and placing the plugin's
>   executable file in the following directory:
>       terraform.d/plugins/linux_amd64

I realized it's because of connectivity issues with https://releases.hashicorp.com domain. For some obvious reasons, we will have to adjust with this connectivity issue as there are some SSL and firewall issues between the control server and Hashicorp's servers.

Is there any way we could bypass this by downloading the plugins from Hashicorp's servers and copying them onto the control server? Or any other alternative to avoid trying to download things from Hashicorp's servers?

Comment: Visit this link for windows 10, corporate firewall: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67178151/12981044

Comment: Please see my new answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70779192/869951 which is the recommended way of doing it (even terraform-bundle, used as basis for the accepted answer, says to do what I describe in my answer).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use pre-installed plugins by either putting the plugins in the same directory as the `terraform` binary or by setting the [`-plugin-dir` flag](https://www.terraform.io/guides/running-terraform-in-automation.html#pre-installed-plugins).

It's also possible to build a bundle of every provider you need automatically using the [`terraform-bundle` tool](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/tree/master/tools/terraform-bundle).

I run Terraform in our CI pipeline in a Docker container so have a Dockerfile that looks something like this:

```dockerfile
FROM golang:alpine AS terraform-bundler-build

RUN apk --no-cache add git unzip && \
    go get -d -v github.com/hashicorp/terraform && \
    go install ./src/github.com/hashicorp/terraform/tools/terraform-bundle

COPY terraform-bundle.hcl .

RUN terraform-bundle package terraform-bundle.hcl && \
    mkdir -p terraform-bundle && \
    unzip -d terraform-bundle terraform_*.zip

####################

FROM python:alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache git make && \
    pip install awscli

COPY --from=terraform-bundler-build /go/terraform-bundle/* /usr/local/bin/
```

Note that the finished container image also adds `git`, `make` and the AWS CLI as I also require those tools in the CI jobs that uses this container.

The `terraform-bundle.hcl` then looks something like this (taken from the [`terraform-bundle` README](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/tree/master/tools/terraform-bundle#usage)):

```hcl
terraform {
  # Version of Terraform to include in the bundle. An exact version number
  # is required.
  version = "0.10.0"
}

# Define which provider plugins are to be included
providers {
  # Include the newest "aws" provider version in the 1.0 series.
  aws = ["~> 1.0"]

  # Include both the newest 1.0 and 2.0 versions of the "google" provider.
  # Each item in these lists allows a distinct version to be added. If the
  # two expressions match different versions then _both_ are included in
  # the bundle archive.
  google = ["~> 1.0", "~> 2.0"]

  # Include a custom plugin to the bundle. Will search for the plugin in the 
  # plugins directory, and package it with the bundle archive. Plugin must have
  # a name of the form: terraform-provider-*, and must be build with the operating
  # system and architecture that terraform enterprise is running, e.g. linux and amd64
  customplugin = ["0.1"]
}
```

Comment: okay for example, https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform-provider-template/ has multiple templates, should I download all the plugins from the above url? or the higher version is okay? If I download each of them, I feel it would be too heavy.

Comment: You should use the version you need. If you don't need to pin to a specific version for some reason you should only use the latest one. I would recommend defining the provider versions you need in your Terraform code (see https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html#provider-versions) and using the pessimistic version constraint operator (`~>`) to restrict it to a single major version and avoid API breaking changes being automatically pulled in/used.

Comment: This is broken on master right now as they roll out 0.12. You'll need to pin to 0.11.9 until 0.12 is fully released. See https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/19173 for more info

Comment: The detailed documentation is found at How Terraform Works: Discovery.  See https://www.terraform.io/docs/extend/how-terraform-works.html#discovery

Comment: Hey @ydaetskcoR, I've added new answer as we have network mirror functionality starting 0.13.2. I would request you to review it once please :)

Answer (score 4):

config plugin_cache_dir in `.terraformrc`

```
plugin_cache_dir   = "$HOME/.terraform.d/plugin-cache"
```

then move the pre-installed provider into the plugin_cache_dir,

terraform will not download the provider anymore

btw, use the ~/.terraform.d/plugin directory doesn't work

```
/.terraform.d/plugin/linux_amd64$ terraform -v
Terraform v0.12.15
```

Comment: could you share the full dockerfile. I am facing an issue with Terraform 0.13.7

Comment: Do you need to include linux_amd64 suffix in the plugin-dir arg path?

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to handle this since terraform 0.14, as also discussed on the terraform-bundle page mentioned in the currently accepted answer, is to use `terraform providers mirror` as described on https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/providers/mirror. This command creates all the necessary index files etc so the folder can be used for plugins. Eg:

```
$ cd your-tf-root-module
$ terraform providers mirror path/to/tf-plugins
...
$ terraform init --plugin-dir path/to/tf-plugins
...
```

You can cd to each of your root modules (ie those that have terraform state) and run the mirror command; multiple versions of a plugin may be installed there, and that's ok. When you run the terraform init command, it will fetch the proper one. Same as without the --plugin-dir arg.

So the only difference is that the internet is not used to acquire the plugins, terraform init gets them from the plugin folder.

This is very useful also for creating a cache that can then be used by terraform in ci/cd. Eg in circleci you would have a manual job that calls mirror and does a save-cache; and your automated terraform init job would restore-cache, and use --plugin-dir arg; then the automated terraform apply job would behave as usual.

Answer (score 2):

Starting 0.13.2 version of Terraform release, one could download plugins from a local webserver/http server via network mirror protocol.

For more details, check [this link](https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/provider-network-mirror-protocol.html)

It expects a `.terraformrc` file in $HOME path, pointing to the provider path of the plugins like below.  If the file is in different directory, you could provide the path with `TERRAFORM_CONFIG` env var.

```
provider_installation {
  network_mirror {
    url    = "https://terraform-plugins.example.net/providers/"
  }
}
```

Then, you define providers in a custom tf like below.

providers.tf::

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "registry.terraform.io/example/azurerm"
    }
    openstack = {
      source  = "registry.terraform.io/example/openstack"
    }
    null = {
      source  = "registry.terraform.io/example/null"
    }
    random = {
      source  = "registry.terraform.io/example/random"
    }
    local = {
      source  = "registry.terraform.io/example/local"
    }
  }
}
```

However, you have to upload the plugin file in `.zip` format along with `index.json` and the `<version>.json` files for terraform to discover the version of plugin to download.

Example index.json containing the version of plugin::

```
{
  "versions": {
    "2.3.0": {}
  }
}
```

Again, 2.3.0.json contains hashes of the plugin file. In this case it's `<version>.json`

```
{
  "archives": {
    "linux_amd64": {
      "hashes": [
        "h1:nFL6uiwsQFLiP8QCr35sPfWe9LpXI3/c7gP9tYnih+k="
      ],
      "url": "terraform-provider-random_2.3.0_linux_amd64.zip"
    }
  }
}
```

> How do you get details of `index.json` and `<version>.json` files?

By running `terraform providers` on the directory containing tf files. Note, the machine running this command, needs to connect to public terraform registry. Terraform will download the information of these files. If you have different terraform configuration files, it makes sense to automate these steps otherwise, you could manually do :)

Upon, `terraform init`, terraform downloads the plugins from above web server rather from terraform registry. Make sure you **don't** use `plugin-dir` argument with `terraform init` as it will override all the changes you made.

Comment: This is going in the right direction but is a bit misleading in that at least in tf 1.0 you dont need to create all these files you mention.

Answer (score 1):

Updated `Dockerfile` for @ydaetskcoR 's solution, because currently `terraform-bundle` doesn't work with 0.12.x (the problem was fixed at 0.12.2, but appeared on 0.12.18)

```
FROM hashicorp/terraform:0.12.18 as terraform-provider

COPY provider.tf .

RUN terraform init && \
    mv .terraform/plugins/linux_amd64/terraform-provider* /bin/ 

FROM hashicorp/terraform:0.12.18
# Install terraform pre-installed plugins
COPY --from=terraform-provider /bin/terraform-provider* /bin/
```

And here is the content of `provider.tf`

```
provider "template" { version = "~>2.1.2" }
provider "aws" { version = "~>2.15.0" }
...
```

Comment: Great solution but mv step is falling. I am using terraform 0.13.7
If possible could you share the updated dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

This took me awhile, had the same problem. I ended up having to download from source and use the image that this spits out. Its nasty, but it does what i need it do to to work with the Google provider.

```
FROM golang:alpine AS terraform-bundler-build

ENV TERRAFORM_VERSION=0.12.20
ENV GOOGLE_PROVIDER=3.5.0

RUN apk add --update --no-cache git make tree bash curl
ENV GOPATH=/go
RUN mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.com/terraform-providers

RUN cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/terraform-providers && curl -sLO https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google-beta/archive/v$GOOGLE_PROVIDER.tar.gz
RUN cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/terraform-providers && tar xvzf v$GOOGLE_PROVIDER.tar.gz && mv terraform-provider-google-beta-$GOOGLE_PROVIDER terraform-provider-google-beta
RUN cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google-beta && pwd &&  make build

RUN cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/terraform-providers && curl -sLO https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/archive/v$GOOGLE_PROVIDER.tar.gz
RUN cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/terraform-providers && tar xvzf v$GOOGLE_PROVIDER.tar.gz && mv terraform-provider-google-$GOOGLE_PROVIDER terraform-provider-google
RUN cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google && pwd &&  make build

RUN mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.com/hashicorp
RUN cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hashicorp && curl -sLO https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/archive/v$TERRAFORM_VERSION.tar.gz
RUN cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hashicorp && tar xvzf v$TERRAFORM_VERSION.tar.gz && mv terraform-$TERRAFORM_VERSION terraform
RUN cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hashicorp/terraform && go install ./tools/terraform-bundle
ENV TF_DEV=false
ENV TF_RELEASE=true
COPY my-build.sh $GOPATH/src/github.com/hashicorp/terraform/scripts/
RUN cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hashicorp/terraform && /bin/bash scripts/my-build.sh
ENV HOME=/root
COPY terraformrc $HOME/.terraformrc
RUN mkdir -p $HOME/.terraform.d/plugin-cache

########################################
FROM alpine:3
ENV HOME=/root

RUN ["/bin/sh", "-c", "apk add --update --no-cache bash ca-certificates curl git jq openssh"]

RUN ["bin/sh", "-c", "mkdir -p /src"]
COPY --from=terraform-bundler-build /go/bin/terraform* /bin/
RUN mkdir -p /root/.terraform.d/plugins/linux_amd64
COPY --from=terraform-bundler-build /root/.terraform.d/ $HOME/.terraform.d/
RUN cp /bin/terraform-provider-google $HOME/.terraform.d/plugin-cache/linux_amd64
RUN cp /bin/terraform-provider-google-beta $HOME/.terraform.d/plugin-cache/linux_amd64

COPY terraformrc $HOME/.terraformrc

COPY provider.tf $HOME/
COPY backend.tf $HOME/

# For Testing (This should be echoed or taken care of in the CI pipeline)
#COPY google.json $HOME/.google.json
WORKDIR $HOME
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

.terraformrc:

```
plugin_cache_dir   = "$HOME/.terraform.d/plugins/linux_amd64"
disable_checkpoint = true
```

provider.tf

```
# Define which provider plugins are to be included
provider "google" {
  credentials = ".google.json"
}

provider "google-beta" {
  credentials = ".google.json"
}
```

my-build.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# This script builds the application from source for multiple platforms.

# Get the parent directory of where this script is.
SOURCE="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
while [ -h "$SOURCE" ] ; do SOURCE="$(readlink "$SOURCE")"; done
DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )/.." && pwd )"

# Change into that directory
cd "$DIR"
echo "DIR=$DIR"

# Get the git commit
GIT_COMMIT=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
GIT_DIRTY=$(test -n "`git status --porcelain`" && echo "+CHANGES" || true)

# Determine the arch/os combos we're building for
XC_ARCH=${XC_ARCH:-"amd64 arm"}
XC_OS=${XC_OS:-linux}
XC_EXCLUDE_OSARCH="!darwin/arm !darwin/386"

mkdir -p bin/

# If its dev mode, only build for ourself
if [[ -n "${TF_DEV}" ]]; then
    XC_OS=$(go env GOOS)
    XC_ARCH=$(go env GOARCH)

    # Allow LD_FLAGS to be appended during development compilations
    LD_FLAGS="-X main.GitCommit=${GIT_COMMIT}${GIT_DIRTY} $LD_FLAGS"
fi

if ! which gox > /dev/null; then
    echo "==> Installing gox..."
    go get -u github.com/mitchellh/gox
fi

# Instruct gox to build statically linked binaries
export CGO_ENABLED=0

# In release mode we don't want debug information in the binary
if [[ -n "${TF_RELEASE}" ]]; then
    LD_FLAGS="-s -w"
fi

# Ensure all remote modules are downloaded and cached before build so that
# the concurrent builds launched by gox won't race to redundantly download them.
go mod download

# Build!
echo "==> Building..."
gox \
    -os="${XC_OS}" \
    -arch="${XC_ARCH}" \
    -osarch="${XC_EXCLUDE_OSARCH}" \
    -ldflags "${LD_FLAGS}" \
    -output "pkg/{{.OS}}_{{.Arch}}/${PWD##*/}" \
    .


## Move all the compiled things to the $GOPATH/bin
GOPATH=${GOPATH:-$(go env GOPATH)}
case $(uname) in
    CYGWIN*)
        GOPATH="$(cygpath $GOPATH)"
        ;;
esac
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=: MAIN_GOPATH=($GOPATH)
IFS=$OLDIFS
#
# Create GOPATH/bin if it's doesn't exists
if [ ! -d $MAIN_GOPATH/bin ]; then
    echo "==> Creating GOPATH/bin directory..."
    mkdir -p $MAIN_GOPATH/bin
fi

# Copy our OS/Arch to the bin/ directory
DEV_PLATFORM="./pkg/$(go env GOOS)_$(go env GOARCH)"
if [[ -d "${DEV_PLATFORM}" ]]; then
    for F in $(find ${DEV_PLATFORM} -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f); do
        cp ${F} bin/
        cp ${F} ${MAIN_GOPATH}/bin/
        ls -alrt ${MAIN_GOPATH}/bin/
        echo "MAIN_GOPATH=${MAIN_GOPATH}"
    done
fi
```

bucket.tf

```
terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket = "my-terraform-bucket"
    prefix = "terraform/state"
    credentials = ".google.json"
  }
  required_version = "v0.12.20"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pre-installed plugins by either putting the plugins binaries in the same directory where Terraform binary is available by setting the "plugins-dir" flag.

By default, all plugins downloaded in .terraform folder. For example, Null resource plugin will be available at below location

.terraform\providers\registry.terraform.io\hashicorp\null\3.0.0.\windows_amd64.

Create new folder like "terraform-plugins" inside Terraform directory and copy all content including registry.terraform.io folder mentioned in above example in created folder.

Now run the terraform init command with plugins-dir flag

terraform init -plugin-dir="/terraform-plugins"

specify complete directory path with plugin-dir flag