# Can and how do you use Terraform providers in secure/disconnected environments?

Tags: terraform

Does anyone have ideas/experience with using Terraform in an environment disconnected from the Internet?

Trying to determine the best approach for acquiring the needed providers and resources to do deployments in a disconnected environment.

Comment: What's your exact question here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50944611/498256

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the plugin cache and place the providers downloaded from https://releases.hashicorp.com/ or populated automatically via `terraform init`.

Configure the path to the plugin cache directory in `.terraformrc`:

```
plugin_cache_dir = "$HOME/.terraform.d/plugin-cache"
```

or via an environment variable:

```
export TF_PLUGIN_CACHE_DIR="$HOME/.terraform.d/plugin-cache"
```

This is well-described in the [Terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html#provider-plugin-cache).