# Terraform init failed with Error: Failed to install provider read: connection reset by peer

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Recently, I've got the problem when running terraoform init. The error showed as below:

```
>terraform init     
                              
Initializing modules...

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/template from the dependency lock file
- Reusing previous version of cloudflare/cloudflare from the dependency lock file
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/aws from the dependency lock file
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/null from the dependency lock file
- Installing hashicorp/template v2.2.0...
- Using previously-installed cloudflare/cloudflare v3.18.0
- Installing hashicorp/aws v3.30.0...
- Installing hashicorp/null v3.1.1...
╷
│ Error: Failed to install provider
│ 
│ Error while installing hashicorp/template v2.2.0: Get "https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform-provider-template/2.2.0/terraform-provider-template_2.2.0_linux_amd64.zip": read tcp 10.250.192.121:45540->108.157.30.78:443: read:
│ connection reset by peer
╵

╷
│ Error: Failed to install provider
│ 
│ Error while installing hashicorp/aws v3.30.0: Get "https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform-provider-aws/3.30.0/terraform-provider-aws_3.30.0_linux_amd64.zip": read tcp 10.250.192.121:37686->108.157.30.40:443: read: connection reset
│ by peer
╵

╷
│ Error: Failed to install provider
│ 
│ Error while installing hashicorp/null v3.1.1: Get "https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform-provider-null/3.1.1/terraform-provider-null_3.1.1_linux_amd64.zip": read tcp 10.250.192.121:45552->108.157.30.78:443: read: connection reset
│ by peer
```

I suppose I need to add some additional configuration relating to network in my server? (IT team just added the new cert in the compary network system)

Comment: I think it just took too long to finish. It could be a firewall issue if it's not a stateful one.

Comment: You can predownload the plugins, see the following posting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50944395/use-pre-installed-terraform-plugins-instead-of-downloading-them-with-terraform-i